# how to return the text of a option inside a optgroup?

Tags: javascript, html, select, label, optgroup

ok, so this is the code

```
<select name="book" id="book">
                <optgroup label="Camus">
                <option>The Outsider</option>
                <option>The Rebel</option>
                <option>The Plague</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Orwell">
                <option>Animal Farm</option>
                <option>Nineteen Eighty-Four</option>
                <option>Down and Out in Paris and London</option>
            </optgroup>
</select>
```

and i want to have a var to take the text of the second option of the first `optgroup` (which in this case it is "The Rebel")
lets say i have
`var x = document.getElementById("book")......`
what i need to put on the rest of the var to get the value i want? 
(Javascript only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to access "The Rebel", just reference the second option within your existing `<select>` element using the `options` property:

```
// Reference the second option in your element to retrieve "The Rebel"
var theRebel = document.getElementById("book").options[1].value;
```

The `options` will ignore any `optgroups` and simply return all of the inner `option` elements that are available. If you wanted to actually use the available `optgroups`, you might consider using the [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function that allows for a bit more querying flexability :

```
// Get the first <option> from the first <optgroup> (i.e. "The Outsider")
document.querySelector('#book optgroup:nth-child(1) option:nth-child(1)').value
// Get the first <option> from the second <optgroup> (i.e. "Animal Farm")
document.querySelector('#book optgroup:nth-child(2) option:nth-child(1)').value
```

**Example**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("book");
alert(x.options[1].value);
```

```html
<select name="book" id="book">
  <optgroup label="Camus">
    <option>The Outsider</option>
    <option>The Rebel</option>
    <option>The Plague</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Orwell">
    <option>Animal Farm</option>
    <option>Nineteen Eighty-Four</option>
    <option>Down and Out in Paris and London</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: tnx, this is exacly what i was looking for, i had search everywhere but i could not figure out how i could do it

Comment: isnt the second way jquery? i am kind of new and i dont know much, i was thinking like, having a var getting the label name from optgroup 1(Camus) and then checking the options of that, like "x = document.getElementById("book").label , or htmlfor (well thoses 2 dont work but as i just said i dont know much) and then having x.option[1] or something

Comment: It's *like* jQuery, however it's native Javascript. It's very similar to how jQuery uses selectors although some of the functionality differs.